# Pyspark - How to remove characters after a match

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark data frame and where I have one column as something like this. and I want to remove `/ccc` from the string.

I am trying few things in pyspark but nothing is working. do I need UDF for this?

`/aaa/bbb/ccc`

In python I could have done like.

```
%python 
"/".join("aaa/bbb/ccc".split("/")[:-1])
```

I tried following. however it generates `null`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, udf, col
def get_path(str):
  "/".join(str.split("/")[:-1])

getPathUDF = udf(lambda z:get_path(z),StringType())   
display(df.withColumn("Path", getPathUDF(col("col6"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html) and extract all characters before the last `/` in the string:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=spark.createDataFrame([["/aaa/bbb/ccc"]], schema=["col"])
df.withColumn("extr", F.regexp_extract("col",r'(.+)(/.+)$',1 )).show()
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------+
|         col|    extr|
+------------+--------+
|/aaa/bbb/ccc|/aaa/bbb|
+------------+--------+
```